# cannot read all the columns from csv using oledb

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, oledb

I have a csv file with the following header:
    **"Pickup Date"**,**"Pickup Time","Pickup Address","From Zone"**, and so on..
    I can only read the first 2 columns and nothing beyond using oledb. I used a schema.ini file with all column names specified. Pls suggest.

**Here is my sample csv.**

```
"PickupDate","PickupTime","PickupAddress","FromZone"
"11/05/15","4:00:00 AM","9 Houston Rd, CityName, NC 28262,","262"
```

**Here is my code:**

```
Schema.ini
-----------
[ReportResults.csv]
ColNameHeader = True
Format = CSVDelimited
col1=Pickup Date DateTime
col2=Pickup Time Text width 100
col3=Pickup Address Text width 500
col4=FromZone short

oledb code
-----------      

     public static DataTable SelectCSV(string path, string query)
     {
      // since the file contains addresses with , the delimiter ", is used. Each cell is written within "" in  the file.
                  var strConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path +
                                "; Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(\",)'";

                  OleDbConnection selectConnection = (OleDbConnection)null;
                  OleDbDataAdapter oleDbDataAdapter = (OleDbDataAdapter)null;


                      selectConnection = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
                      selectConnection.Open();
                      using(OleDbCommand cmd=new OleDbCommand(query,selectConnection))
                      using (oleDbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                      {
                          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                          dt.Locale=CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                          oleDbDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                          return dt;
                      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every column is contained in double quotes so every comma inside a double quote is not considered as delimeter.

So you can import your file:

- without using `schema.ini`
- specifying `EXTENDED PROPERTIES='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited'` in your connection string

If you need to use a schema to solve other problems please note that your `schema.ini` is not formally correct; use something like this:

```
[ReportResults.csv]
ColNameHeader = True
Format = CSVDelimited
col1=PickupDate DateTime
col2=PickupTime Text width 100
col3=PickupAddress Text width 500
col4=FromZone short
```

If you have problem extracting `DateTime` column specify `DateTimeFormat` options; i.e. if your pickup date is something like 2015/11/13 specify `DateTimeFormat=yyyy/MM/dd=yyyy/MM/dd`.

If you have problem extracting `Short` column verify that FromZone is an integer between -32768 and 32767; if not, use a different type. You can also set `DecimalSymbol` option if you have problem with decimal separators.

You can find more info on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thankyou for your response. I have tried the suggested schema.ini format too. But did not help. Well the address is a text, it doesnt read that either.

Comment: can you post an extract of your csv file?

Comment: Sure. I have added a sample row from the csv.

Comment: I have tried both by placing spaces in the column names (pickup Date) and by removing the space as well (PickupDate)

Comment: you are using double quote and comma: try delete `schema.ini` and specify `EXTENDED PROPERTIES='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited'`

Comment: ", is used as delimiter because the address columns have values separated by comma.

Comment: yes, but every column is contained in double quotes so every comma inside a double quote is not considered as delimeter.

Comment: The above suggestion worked well :) Thanks a ton Tezzo :)